# word problem - hoe to find area from work done and days

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A farmer planned to plough a field by doing 120 hectares a day. After
> two days of work he increased his daily productivity by 25% and he
> finished the job two days ahead of schedule.
>
> a) What is the area of the field?
>
> b) In how many days did the farmer get the job done?
>
> c) In how many days did the farmer plan to get the job done?

The only thing I am able to work out from here is $25\%$ of $120$ hectares a day, which is $30$, so on day 2 he works $150$ hectares a day and finishes the job two days earlier than planned, but I am not sure how to put this into algebra and work out area?

Comment: After two days of work means that he first ploughs $150$ hectares on the third day of work.

Comment: Wow I'm not a farmer, I don't [feel included](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29144/heteronormativity-and-binary-gender-assumptions) in this word problem! Please edit! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of expected days (ploughing 120 hectares a day) is $x$ you have $120x = A$ where $A$ is the total area.

Instead the farmer increased the workload after two days to $150$, as you stated.

In the first two days they plowed $240$ hectares, so in this new set up the total area can be seen as $240 + 150n = A$ where $n$ is the total number of days they ploughs $150$ hectares. You can see that $x - 2 = n + 2$, so $n = x-4$.

You now have $240 + 150(x-4) = 120x$ which you can rearrange to give $x = 12$. From here it follows that $A = 1440$, and $n = 8$. (Actual days spent ploughing $=10$)